# Python BeautifulSoup html parsing

Tags: python, html, css, parsing, beautifulsoup

New to Webscraping, and trying to parse html of http://www.airportcodes.org and get airport codes along with city name and state into a dataframe. HTML looks like the below. Basically it seems like after every 'div class="t6" tag, lines of items (city, state, and airport code) I need to parse are listed there with a break tag, but since they are sectioned alphabetically, the number of items in each section differs.

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
<tr><td bgcolor="#CBC7E0"><img height="2" src="img/0.gif" width="1"/></td></tr>
</table></div>
<a name="USA"></a>
<div class="t6"><div class="major"><b>A</b></div></div>

Aberdeen, SD (ABR) <br/>
Abilene, TX (ABI)<br/>
Adak Island, AK (ADK)<br/>
Akiachak, AK (KKI)<br/>
Akiak, AK (AKI)<br/>
Akron/Canton, OH (CAK)<br/>
Akuton, AK (KQA)<br/>
Alakanuk, AK (AUK)<br/>
Alamogordo, NM (ALM)<br/>
...

<div class="sectionBreak">
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
<tr><td bgcolor="#CBC7E0"><img height="2" src="img/0.gif" width="1"/></td></tr>
</table></div>
<div align="right"><div align="right"><a href="#top">return to top</a></div></div>
<a name="USB"></a>
<div class="t6"><div class="major"><b>B</b></div></div>

Bakersfield, CA (BFL)<br/>
Baltimore, MD (BWI)<br/>
Bangor, ME (BGR)<br/>
Bar Harbour, ME (BHB)<br/>
...
```

Codes so far:

```
import bs4 as bs
sauce = urllib.request.urlopen('http://www.airportcodes.org/').read()
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(sauce, 'lxml')

for tag in soup.find_all("div", class_="t6"):
    print(tag.next_sibling)
```

gets me:

```
Aberdeen, SD (ABR) 


Bakersfield, CA (BFL)


Canton/Akron, OH (CAK)
```

But this is wrong as it looks like the code is only returning the first item next to the specified tag. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to extract the `br` tags, to read properly the text result.

Then you can loop over `type(tag)` and test if it is a `bs4.element.NavigableString`

Try this:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import bs4

url = "http://www.airportcodes.org/"
resp = requests.get(url)

page = soup(resp.text, 'html.parser')
for br in page.find_all('br'):
    br.extract()

for tag in page.find_all("div", class_="t6"):
    while type(tag.next_sibling) is bs4.element.NavigableString:
        tag = tag.next_sibling
        print(tag)
```

**Result:**

```
Aberdeen, SD (ABR) 
Easton, PA (ABE)
...
...
Island Lake/Garden Hill, Canada (YIV)
Islay, United Kingdom (ILY)
```

Comment: thanks, this seems to almost work, but removes some of the values (airport codes), i.e. not getting all the result desired. Any help?

Comment: getting the same result as you, but you notice, there's only 1 value starting with an 'A', which is Aberdeen, SD (ABR), but as you can see from my original post, the next value is Abilene, TX (ABI), and this is nowhere to be found

Answer (score 0):

Use `find_next_siblings(text=True)` to get all the Airport Info.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
r=requests.get("http://www.airportcodes.org/").content
soup=BeautifulSoup(r,'html.parser')
for items in soup.select('div.t6'):
   for item in items.find_next_siblings(text=True):
       print(item)
```

Comment: thanks, this seems to almost work, but removes some of the values (airport codes), i.e. not getting all the result desired. Any help?

Comment: @Si_CPyR : can you provide an example which airport code you are getting problem to diagnos?